# Careers PDF export, redundant commas between tags

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

Using the `create pdf` link you can generate a resume from your careers profile.

However, the "Projects & Interests" section lists tags associated with entries with doubled commas. For example, my Plone entry is tagged as "plone,, zope,, python" in the resulting PDF.

I like screenshots, so here are some to illustrate this. This is the Plone section on my Open Source projects section:

[image: Plone section]

and here is the preview for the PDF generation for this section:

[image: Plone section in the PDF preview]

with the actual PDF also containing the doubled commas.

Comment: They're RAID1 commas. What if something happens to the first comma? You'd look quite the fool.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A fix for this is flowing through the pipe now.

Comment: Fix confirmed, thanks!